# Google sheets split text into multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have some text that is a mixture of these formats:
In Column A

```
1 2 [7] Random Text
1 [7] Random Text
[7] Random Text
```

and
In Column B

```
Random Text 1 2 [7]
Random Text 1 [7]
Random Text [7]
```

I need to separate the text and numbers in separate columns.
Something like

```
| 1 | 2 | [7] | Random Text
|   | 1 | [7] | Random Text
|   |   | [7] | Random Text
```

and

```
Random Text | 1 | 2 | [7] |
Random Text |   | 1 | [7] |
Random Text |   |   | [7] |
```

I tried this but can't get it to work.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(I2, ".*\[.]", "")
```

The idea is to split the different formats into separate columns. The text, The number and the number with `[]`

Thanks

Comment: the issue is the `Random Text`. Otherwise you could easily separated by space: `Split(I2," ")`

Comment: So, `Random Text` would always be either at the beginning or at the end? Also, the numbers would always come before the numbers with `[]`?

Comment: @Iamblichus Yes to both but it the numbers with [] is missing then we'll only have a number with the Random Text.

Comment: @mary, having seen my fair share of such scenarios presented, I have a suspicion that there are more exceptions than you've included. I could write the formulas for EXACTLY what you've presented, but it will be no good if you have other cases. The best way to receive efficient and effective help is to share a link to your sheet (or a copy of your sheet, or a true representative sample from your sheet), being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link can edit."

Comment: For instance, following what I said above, you've now said in the comments here "[if] the numbers with the [] is missing then..." But you don't show any entries in your post where the number is missing from the []. Or, is it possible that your "Random Text" will contain numbers like zip codes or phone numbers in real application; or punctuation or special characters? Again, there is still too much unknown to really help without guesswork (and the subsequent wasted time). Please consider sharing that link.

Comment: You're right @ErikTyler. Please take a look here at my file here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GMYudQx1sH4gnvktMxhqdzA1a3-P_tz0FA3rRhbAbgA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @mary, thank you for sharing the sheet. It proves my case. Your "Column B" examples in your post don't match your actual Column B data at all (the order of where the brackets are is wrong). There are many more formats than shown in any of your post examples. And you have got plenty of special and international characters throughout. I will do my best to look at this later today; but for now I can only say that it is more complex than explained in your post and quite possibly beyond what a free forum can offer as it will require what I'd call "real client-level" work to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mary, I did dive into your sheet. And it is complex. However, I did add a sheet with my formula solutions. The formulas in D1, E1 and G1 process Column A (with the E1 formula pulling double duty and producing results for Columns E and F). Here are those formulas:

In D1:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",,IFERROR(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"([øa-zA-Z0-9-\/ ]+)$")))))
```

In E1:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",,IFERROR(SPLIT(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(" ",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,D:D,""),G:G,"")))),"~ "&TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,D:D,""),G:G,"")),TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,D:D,""),G:G,"")))," ",1,0)*1)))
```

In G1:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"(\[[0-9]+\])"))))
```

These formulas are *inter-dependent*. That is, while the formulas in D1 and G1 can stand alone, the formula in E1 relies upon the results from the other two formulas.

In the same way as above, there are formulas in I1, J1 and L1, which process Column B. The formulas in J1 and L1 are the same relative to the formulas in E1 and G1 (with obvious references shifted to accommodate the new column and relative location). The formula in I1 is different from the D1 formula, because of the location and other factors. That formula:

In I1:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B:B="",,TRIM(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B:B,"^([øa-zA-Z-\/ ]+)"))&IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B:B," [0-9]{4}")))))
```

These formulas accommodate all cases currently represented in your sample data. If your actual data varies from this in additional characters or configurations, the results for such rows will be unpredictable.

Typically, I explain my solutions in detail. However, just providing this solution itself took far more time than I'd typically spend answering forum questions in a whole day. So I've chosen to provide the answers rather than skip the post altogether; and I invite anyone who is interested to dive into REGEX to understand how they work.

Comment: Looks like the formula for the first column is leaving out some characters. Please check Column D. Example D273, D276, D277 have some numbers. The right side formula I-L is spot on.

Comment: with the help of this formula ```=JOIN(" ",SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1," ")),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(A1," "))),0))``` I reversed the order so that I can use the formula for the second part. Thanks for the great help.

Comment: Wasn't successful with my formula above. It alters words as well. :(

Comment: I edited D1: =ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",,IFERROR(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"([a-zA-Z][øa-zA-Z0-9-\/ ]+)$")))))

Comment: Perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use for first case:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A:A),REGEXEXTRACT(IF(REGEXMATCH(A:A,"^\d\s\[")," " & A:A,A:A),"^(\d)*\s*(\d)*\s*(\[\d*\])*\s*(.+)$"),""))
```

for second:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B:B),REGEXEXTRACT(B:B,"^(.*?)(\s*\[\d*\])*(\s*\d*)(\s*\d*)$"),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the formula. Is it possible to put the [] in a separate column from the text and whole numbers i.e those without []?

Comment: Do you mean - remove square brackets from number? Then include ```LEFT``` function for first case and ```RIGHT``` function for second case into ```REGEXPREPLACE```, i.e. ```REGEXREPLACE(LEFT(A:A,SEARCH("]",A:A)),"\[|\]","")```

Comment: No. I mean like this  ```| 1 | [3] | Random Text``` I mean like each format on it's own column. I have given an example in the link.

Comment: @maryongubo I found a solution with ```REGEXEXTRACT```, had to rewrite the formulas completely. See edit.